# Actors pattern and counter in a cluster how do they go along?

Tags: scala, concurrency, erlang, closures, actor

I have a cluster of 20 servers.
I want them to send 200 emails (for example).
Now  each node decides in its own based on some rules to send an email.  HOw can I make them altogether not to send more thank 200 emails?  And still be highly scalable and accurate with high performance (so will also work for 200G emails with 200 nodes... Just for example.

If I have a shared memory with a counter won't that be a contention point? If I use actors and messaging I might get huge mistakes in number of ״s
Emails" send.

In other words how does a global cluster wide counter which is read and updated by any node in cluster ++ or -- goes along with no synchronization and contention - with actor / asynchronous / messaging patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How fast are you going to send those e-mails? What throughput are you looking at? Just a simple counter shared by 200 nodes doesn't sound too horrible. Is this a real bottleneck you are talking about or are you just trying to prematurely optimize the system?

A really simple trick if the counter is a bottleneck is to not check the counter for every single e-mail, but cache it locally on the node for, say, a few hundred e-mails.

Comment: hi i'm sorry, the "email" was just for an example basically, I do need to send something to users over the web the issue is that it should be very very very highly scalable, and as i have a cluster then each node cannot decide alone to how many people its going to send these messages because its dependant on how many messages other nodes are going to send, for that reason i need some kind of control - a counter, problem is that a shared memory counter in the intranet seems to me like a very good candidate to proove to be a bottleneck. Any pattern already exists for such highly scalable syst?

Comment: Why do you depend on how many messages other nodes are sending? Just divide the work between the nodes, possibly in a tree-like fashion to get some extra scalability. You can have half the cluster doing the first part of the list, and the other half does the second part. Then divide it further into smaller and smaller sublists and smaller subclusters, until each node in the cluster have their own list of people to send messages to. You can also divide the cluster just with regards of number of messages, for example "this subcluster may send that many messages" and have a more local counter.

Comment: when you say "divide the work between the nodes" doesn't that means there would need to be some centralized entity that would be aware of all my nodes and would need to start dividing the workload between the nodes? this would mean i need to take care of that primary entity? (trying to avoid "primaries..." in order to be highly available)

Comment: You are indeed correct. But I still think your question is pretty vague. I have a hard time understanding what your actual problem is. Where would the nodes get their workload from otherwise. Do they have any shared state? I think you should clarify your question better.

Comment: OK I think i get the answer.  I should either lock or try to get some other ways of doing this, and other ways might compromise consistency for performance.